# Elasticsearch Copy_to data need to copied self subdocument

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

Thanks in advance for helping.

I have created ES mapping as :

```
{"mappings": {
            "policy": {
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "tags": {
                        "properties": {
                            "scope": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "store": "true",
                                "copy_to": [
                                    "tags.tag_scope"
                                ]
                            },
                            "tag": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "store": "true",
                                "copy_to": [
                                    "tags.tag_scope"
                                ]
                            },
                            "tag_scope": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "store": "true"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

When i index policy document all tag and scope value from different tags document copied to tag_scope property.

For Example I added a document as to elastic search:

```
{
                    "name": "policy1",
                    "tags": [
                        {
                            "tag": "pepsi",
                            "scope": "prod"
                        },
                        {
                            "tag": "coke",
                            "scope": "dev"
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

It is storing all 4 values as in tag_scope documents as:

"tags.tag_scope": [
                        "pepsi",
                        "test",
                        "coke",
                        "dev"
                    ]

My Exceptions was, it should store like :

```
 {
                        "name": "policy1",
                        "tags": [
                            {
                                "tag": "pepsi",
                                "scope": "prod",
                                 "tag_scope" : ["pepsi","prod"]
                            },
                            {
                                "tag": "coke",
                                "scope": "dev",
                                 "tag_scope" : ["coke","dev"]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
```

Could you please help me to do correct mapping for same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`Nested Datatype`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html). Change your mapping to the below:

```
PUT <your_index_name>
{  
   "mappings":{  
      "policy":{ 
         "properties":{  
            "name":{  
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{  
                  "keyword":{  
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "tags":{  
               "type": "nested", 
               "properties":{  
                  "scope":{  
                     "type":"text",
                     "store":"true",
                     "copy_to":[  
                        "tags.tag_scope"
                     ]
                  },
                  "tag":{  
                     "type":"text",
                     "store":"true",
                     "copy_to":[  
                        "tags.tag_scope"
                     ]
                  },
                  "tag_scope":{  
                     "type":"text",
                     "store":"true",
                     "fields": {                <---- Added this
                       "keyword": {
                          "type": "keyword"
                       }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Notice how I've made `tags` as [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) type. This would allow the below to be stored as individual document itself, which in your case `tags` basically has two nested documents.

```
{  
   "tag":"coke",
   "scope":"dev"
}
```

*Now your `tags.tag_scope` should be what you are expecting it to be.*

Now when it comes to querying for what you are looking for, the below is how a [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) should be.

### Nested Query:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "tags.tag_scope": "pepsi"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "tags.tag_scope": "prod"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As to return the list of unique `tags.tag_scope` value you would need to return aggregation query. Notice that I've mentioned `size:0` which means I only want to see aggregation result and not normal query results.

### Aggregation Query:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "size":0,
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "nested":{  
                  "path":"tags",
                  "query":{  
                     "bool":{  
                        "must":[  
                           {  
                              "match":{  
                                 "tags.tag_scope":"pepsi"
                              }
                           },
                           {  
                              "match":{  
                                 "tags.tag_scope":"prod"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{                        <----- Aggregation Query Starts Here
      "myscope":{  
         "nested":{  
            "path":"tags"
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "uniqui_scope":{  
               "terms":{  
                  "field":"tags.tag_scope.keyword",
                  "size":10
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

### Aggregation Response:

```
{
  "took": 53,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "myscope": {
      "doc_count": 2,
      "uniqui_scope": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "coke",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "dev",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "pepsi",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "prod",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Kamal, I tried to use nested without copy_to that help me with aggregation search result.

Comment: I tried to run listed search query with your solution mapping, it is not returning any result: {
 "stored_fields" : ["tags.scope", "tags.tag_scope"], 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "tags.tag_scope": "pepsi"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: My use case to get all distinct tag_scope value available in the documents.

Comment: Hey Prakash, your `copy_to` field would not appear in your search result, reason is elasticsearch *doesn't modify* the source document i.e. the document you sent to it during ingestion. Thirdly I'd suggest you to make use of "_source" field in your query instead of "stored_fields" if your goal is to return only certain fields in your response. You can only make use of copy_to field during query. Hope that helps!

Comment: I've updated my answer as you would want to see list of distinct `tag_scope1` value. Notice that I've made `tag_scope` a multi field which has `tag_scope.keyword` field too of type `keyword`. I've used this in order to run aggregation query to fetch list of distinct tag_scope values.